# Using the same Buffered Reader to read the content of each file within a manifest File?

Tags: java, manifest, bufferedreader

Good Morning all -

I have a small question that I feel that I am not understanding correctly. I completed the assignment, but not to the exact structure asked of by the professor.

In it we are supposed to read the a manifest file using the buffered reader and then we are to read the contents of each file within the manifest file.

Ex- 
Manifest.txt

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
```

File1.txt

```
I Like
```

File2.txt

```
Cats.
```

Here is my code - I am still working on understanding everything I write in the program, and I clean it out before I submit. This is more so that I can review and understand what I am doing.

My solution was to create a new file and reading the contents of that file using the scanner. Part of the instructions in the code template was to submit the use the same buffered reader twice to read the File 1 and File 2 within the manifest files. I tried reassigning the name as the line value, and then having the scanner read that. That produces an error:

```
    name=line;
    Scanner readThis = new Scanner(name);
    out.println(readThis);

    java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
```

I would like some guidance on how we could use the buffered reader a second time to read each file within the manifest file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("input manifest file name");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String name = in.nextLine();
    // create  reader and writer object 
    //reads the file name inside of manifest
    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
        //writes a new file with all of the informaiton
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(name+".out")))  {

        String line;
        //reading the manifest file - string line   reads each line of text  
        while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            //for current line of text
            //each line in manifest text is a separate input 
            //this is where i need to take the original buffered reader  and read that line input
            //line is now the name of the current text file 
            //read that text file?


            name=line;
            //each file line is the name, so we can create a new file 
            File inFile = new File(name);
            //the scanner reads the file 
            Scanner readThis = new Scanner(inFile);

            //return true since there is text in the file 
            while (readThis.hasNextLine()) {
                //print the text to the out put file
                out.println(readThis.nextLine());
            }
            }
    **// for each file name, use the same reader to read the content of the file, and write to the output file.**


    // don't forget to flush the writer in the end
        out.flush();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("A file that does not exist or is unavailable has been input");
    }
    in.close();
}
```

}

Thanks for all for the help everyone!

Comment: Well you're supposed to read three or more files, so why do you want to write a file?  That seems weird.  Was the assignment actually to read the files and then make a new file with the contents of all the files concatenated together?  Please clarify.

Comment: You mean the maifest file contains a list of file names, then you start the program passing the manifest file name as a paramenter, and the program has to read the enclosed file names, and the read the content of each of these files. And to do this it is a requirement to use the same BufferedReader for the manifest and the enclosed files. Is it like this how it should work?

Comment: Hi all - 
Yes the list of file names resides in the manifest file. I need to use  the buffered reader to read the content of the manifest file and then use the same buffered reader object to read the the content of each file listed within the file names. 
** instructions inside code template 

// use the reader to read the names of input files from the manifest file and
  
// for each file name, use the same reader to read the content of the file, and write to the output file.